# Remove file extension and rewrite url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to

1. www.website.com/stuff.php to www.website.com/stuff
2. www.website.com/things/stuff.php to wwww.website.com/things/stuff
3. www.website.com/news.php?article=1 to wwww.website.com/news/1

Currently my htaccess is the following, but it only allows for scenario 1 & 2. I have tried other attempts, which got 3 to work, but not 1 & 2. I can't figure out how to get the multiple conditions to coexist.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ /news.php?article=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rules

```
RewriteEngine on

 #remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
 #news/1 to /news.php?article=1
 RewriteRule ^news/(.+)$ /news.php?article=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Conditions 1 & 2 work with that configuration, new the 3 gives 500 error.

The following have to be used to access the news page now: www.website.com/news/?article=5, www.website.com/news?article=5, www.website.com/news.php?article=5